Não consigo gravar mais de 25 números em um arquivo binário
Eu estou estudando leitura e escrita de arquivos com c++, até que eu me deparei com este código.
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream entrada("teste.bin", ios_base::out | ios_base::ate);
    for(unsigned short i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        entrada.write((char*)&i, sizeof(unsigned short));
    }
    entrada.close();

    fstream saida("teste.bin", ios_base::in);
    unsigned short num;
    do
    {
        saida.read((char*)&num, sizeof(unsigned short));
        cout << num << endl;
    } while (!saida.eof());
    saida.close();
}

Minha dúvida e porque no terminal do windows ele só imprimir os 25 primeiros números, mas no linux e seus derivados imprimir os 100 primeiros?


Minha dúvida é porque no terminal do windows ele só imprime os 25 primeiros números, mas no linux e seus derivados imprime os 100 primeiros?

TL;DR; É só uma coincidência e parece uma pegadinha. Não é que ele imprima apenas 25 no Windows, mas sim que em Windows você não consegue ler um byte com valor 26 se não especificar ios::binary no modo de abertura. Se o primeiro byte no arquivo de entrada fosse 26 não ia ler nada. E se gravasse apenas os ímpares de 1 a 199 o programa ia rodar certinho e nem saberia do "problema".
Como gravou de 1 a 100 o programa para ao ler o 26...
Seguem mais detalhes e um programa exemplo.
Faltou especificar ios::binary no modo de abertura ao gravar o arquivo. Como em Windows esse não é o padrão, o tratamento de certos valores na entrada é diferente em MAc/Linux/Android vs Windows.
Tem dois problemas no caminho até 100 no seu programa: o 10 e o 26.

10 é o line feed e vai gerar um 0D a mais na saída, já que é o padrão no Windows: todo line feed por padrão é substituído pelo par return/line feed. 0x0A é trocado por 0x0D0A.
26 é o control-Z: o código para Z é 90, ou 0b01011010. Control zera os bits acima de 64 então z (122) dá na mesma. Só que esse é o indicador de fim de arquivo: Control-Z sinaliza o fim de arquivo desde sempre... Então quando seu programa for ler o arquivo gravado vai parar ao ler o 26 --- 0x1A.

O arquivo gerado:

É o 0A depois de 0D, veja lá na segunda linha. E ao final.
E na hora de ler não vai passar por um 26 se o modo não for binário.
o arquivo gerado usando ios::binary

e esse tem 200 bytes como esperado.
Sobre isso:
        entrada.write((char*)&i, sizeof(unsigned short));

e isso:
        saida.read((char*)&num, sizeof(unsigned short));

Não é toda hora que a gente lê um write na entrada seguido por um read na saída :D
Note que seu programa tem o clássico erro one_off por testar a saída do loop com eof() e assim mostra duas vezes o último número. Nunca faça isso.
exemplo
pode usar algo assim:
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    auto nome = "teste.bin";
    unsigned short num = 0;
    fstream arquivo(
        nome, ios_base::out | ios::binary | ios_base::ate);
    if (not arquivo.good())
    {
        cerr << "Erro ao tentar abrir " << nome << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    for (num = 1; num <= 100; num++)
    {
        arquivo.write(
            (const char*)&num, sizeof(unsigned short));
        if (not arquivo.good())
        {
            cerr << "Erro ao gravar " << num << endl;
            return -3;
        }
    }
    arquivo.close();
    arquivo.open(nome, ios::in | ios::binary);
    if ( not arquivo.good())
    {
        cerr << "Erro ao tentar reabrir " << nome << endl;
        return -2;
    }
    while (arquivo.good())
    {
        arquivo.read((char*)&num, sizeof(unsigned short));
            if ( not arquivo.good()) break;
            cout << num << endl;
    }; 
    arquivo.close();
}

Note que ao encontrar algum erro streams marcam ios::badbit true e esse é um dos indicadores testados por good() e bad().

A conversa ficou extensa e foi movida para o chat; - se necessário, utilizem o link fornecido para prosseguir.
